# Linear Independence of an infinite set 2.

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $e_n=\sin nx$ ($x\in [-\pi,\pi])$and let $A=\{e_i|i\in \mathbb{N}\}$. Prove that A is a linearly independent set.

Some hours back I had posted this question. In the meantime I was trying myself to come up with a proof. Now I have some idea which I am be writing down as an answer. I will ask all of you to evaluate whether this is the correct approach or not?

Comment: You could post this on your previous question and see what the comments are.

Comment: Or you could insert the answer below in the question for more visibility and better organization.

Comment: Ok thanks for the advice.I will post it there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $z=\cos x+i\sin x$ for  $x\in [-\pi,\pi]$ and $A_k=\{e_i|i\in \mathbb{N},i\le k\}$

I will show that every $A_k$ is linearly independent.

If $\displaystyle \sum_{j=1}^{k}\lambda_je_j=0$ be a linear relation. Then I will show $\lambda_j=0,\forall j\le k$.

Now we know that $\sin nx=\frac{1}{2i}(z^n-\frac{1}{z^n})$.

So the relation becomes $\displaystyle \sum_{j=1}^{k}\frac{\lambda_j}{2i}(z^j-\frac{1}{z^j})=0\dots(1)$

Now $|z|=1$ which implies All the $z$ lies on the circle of unit radius.

So $z\ne 0\Rightarrow z^n\ne 0$

Multiplying eqn. (1) with $z^n $ we get,

$\displaystyle z^n\sum_{j=1}^{k}\frac{\lambda_j}{2i}(z^j-\frac{1}{z^j})=0$

$\Rightarrow \displaystyle \sum_{j=1}^{k}\frac{\lambda_j}{2i}(z^{j+n}-z^{n-j})=0$

SO we get a polynomial in $z$ valid for all $z$ such that $|z|=1$

As a polynomial of n degree cant have more that $n$ roots and as this polynomial has infinite roots so this must be the zero polynomial $\Rightarrow \lambda_j=0 ,\forall j\le k$

Now every finite subset will be a subset of some $A_k,k\in N$ .As all $A_k$ are linearly independent it implies that every finite subset will also be linearly independent.

Comment: Yes, this is an alternative to the inner product approach. It works, good job. You can post it on your previous question and delete this one.